# Find the value of : $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x-3}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to <s>solve</s> evaluate this limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x-3}}.$$

I've tried to rationalize the denominator but this is what I've got

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x-2})({\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x-3}})$$

and I don't know how to remove these indeterminate forms $(\infty - \infty)$.

EDIT: without l'Hospital's rule (if possible).

Comment: Do you know l'Hopital?

Comment: I forgot to include that I still hasn't studied l'Hopital.

Comment: The key (as in the answers) is to rationalize the "interesting" part, i.e. the indeterminate parts. There are two of these (both numerator and denominator are indeterminate), so you should rationalize both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fill in details:

As $\;x\to\infty\;$ we can assume $\;x>0\;$ , so:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x-3}}=\frac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x-2}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac2x}+\sqrt{1-\frac3x}}{\sqrt{1-\frac1x}+\sqrt{1-\frac2x}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1$$

Further hint: the first step was multiplying by conjugate of **both** the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: +$1$ Good answer! You beat me to it :)

Comment: @Clayton Thanks. Yet someone didn't like it. Oh, well.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x-2} = \dfrac1{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x-2}}$$
and
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x-3}} = \sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-3}$$
We hence have
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{x-3}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x-2}}$$
We have
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-2}}<\dfrac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x-2}} < 1$$
Now conclude what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply with $\frac{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x-2}}$ aswell. Then it should be easy to evaluate.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x-3}}
&=\frac{\sqrt{x-1} - \sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x-3}}\,\,
\frac{\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x-2}}{\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x-2}}\,\,
\frac{\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x-3}}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{x-1-(x-2)}{x-2-(x-3)}\,\frac{\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x-2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x-2}}\\ \ \\
&=\frac{\sqrt{1-2/x}+\sqrt{1-3/x}}{\sqrt{1-1/x}+\sqrt{1-2/x}}\to\frac22=1
\end{align}